# Spring JPA transaction with thread pool

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I am trying to understand why below code fragment does not work as expected.

I already have `customer` with `id=1234 and name=A1`. I am creating 2 callable tasks and asking them to execute `transnational update` method.

Both the transactions are running together(As i have introduced 1 second of delay after reading customer copy from database as shown in code) and read original customer with `id=1234 and name=A1`

One tries to `update name from A1->A2` and other tries to `update name from A1->A3`

I was expecting at least 1 transaction to throw commit conflict/stale data exception but in below case both succeeds.

Could you help me to understand it well? Am I missing anything conceptually?

**Main.java**

```
    @Autowired
    CustomerService service;

    // Update address from A1 to A2
    Callable<String> t1 = new Callable<String>() {

        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            service.updateCustomer("1234", "A2");
            return "T1 Done";
        }
    };

    // Update address from A1 to A3
    Callable<String> t2 = new Callable<String>() {

        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            service.updateCustomer("1234", "A3");
            return "T2 Done";
        }
    };

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    executorService.invokeAll((Collection) Arrays.asList(t1, t2));
```

**CustomerService.java**

```
@Transactional
public void updateCustomer(String customerId, String customerName) {
    try {
        Optional<Customer> currentCopyHandle = repo.findById(customerId);
        Customer currentCopy = currentCopyHandle.get();

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String customerDetails = currentCopy.getDetails();

        ObjectNode writableDetails = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree(customerDetails);
        writableDetails.put("name", customerName);

        currentCopy.setDetails(mapper.writeValueAsString(writableDetails));

        repo.save(currentCopy);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

**Edit-1**
Customer.java

It's an Oracle 12c compatible POJO, where field with name `details` is marked as `@Lob` and oracle12c table has json constraint

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

@Id
@javax.persistence.Id
private String cid;

@Lob
private String details;

public Customer() {
}

@PersistenceConstructor
public Customer(String cid, String details) {
    super();
    this.cid = cid;
    this.details = details;
}

public String getCid() {
    return cid;
}

public void setCid(String cid) {
    this.cid = cid;
}

public String getDetails() {
    return details;
}

public void setDetails(String details) {
    this.details = details;
}
}
```

Before I started this exercise, I had done below activity.

```
String json = "{ \"cid\" : \"1234\", \"name\" : \"A1\", \"address\" : \"India\"}";

service.saveCustomer1(new Customer("1234", json));
```

Comment: Could you post your code of `Customer` and the definition of `repo`? Not sure how you achieve `update name from A1->A2`.

Comment: What makes you think updating a value should throw an exception? Unless you configure optimistic locking, that won't happen: you update a value, and the value is thus updated.

Comment: @TKJohn : I have added Customer.java as well now. It's Oracle 12c compatible pojo where field with `@Lob` represents `json document`

Comment: @JBNizet : It's similar to below customer bank account analogy

I have account with bank balance as 0 initially.

Tx1 : When I started, customer balance was 0, so let me add $500 and end result will be $500

Tx2: When I started, customer balance was 0, so let me add $100 and end result will be $100

Both transactions start at the same time, they read customer account object from database/cache/mongo, with balance as 0 initially which is nothing but a snapshot copy when transaction started.

But at least 1 of the transaction should be proved wrong while committing.

Comment: @DharamThakkar I understand why you *want* that. But just because you want it doesn't mean that it's what will happen by default.

Comment: @JBNizet: I agree with you. Somewhere I am wrong in concepts. 1 second of delay is actually an indication of external service call. But if I run above mentioned code, it's exactly resulting in a similar way I explained and both succeeds. Could you help me to understand how we should deal with that?

Comment: I already did: you need to use optimistic locking. So, open the Hibernate documentation, search for "optimistic locking", and read.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [JBNizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet)!

Using optimistic locking by adding @Version property to my model here solved my problem.